# Should Functional Testing of an application be part of an application project/build or a seperate project ran independetly

Tags: testing

Let's take an application that provides a REST API. As part of the build process, both unit tests and integration tests are run against it.

At some point we want to spin this application up properly, deploy it, have it speaking to actual third parties systems (e.g. databases) and test it by firing HTTP requests at the application.

Should these functional tests be part of the same project (and build, e.g. Maven) that houses the application, probably with a way to spool up and down the actual application (which might for example involve deploying to an application server) OR should these functional tests be completely seperate, triggered as part of a greater pipeline,  it's own project. Requiring say CI or 'manual' operation (locally) to deal with the deployment of the application rather than part of the application build itself.

I could see for example there being instances where all unit and integration tests pass, however it fails on deployment, meaning the build would not be considered passing.  (Spring DI and missing annotation on a class)

Answer (score 2):

If your project uses a single repository, the answer is fairly uncomplicated: The functional end-to-end tests are logically a part of your project and for that reason they should live in the same repository.

But even then, there might be reasons why you don't want to execute those end-to-end tests on every build that gets done and provide a separate CI pipeline to run those tests on their own schedule (for example, once a day if there has been a commit to the repository).

If multiple repositories are involved, things get more complicated. Especially if there isn't a top-level repo of which you can say "if you want a deployable package, clone that one and all the rest will be pulled in through dependency mechanisms".
If there is a top-level repository, then put the tests in that one. Otherwise, pick one that seems suitable and make sure the tests have their own CI pipeline (so the tests can be triggered also if the repository containing them is unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

There are trade-offs here. [Bart's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/438367/416582) covers some of them.

Our team usually try to consider what the purpose of the specific tests/test suite are:

- Fast feedback
- Prevent regressions/ensure a green deployment
- Audit (in some contexts)

Provided the execution time is short enough to be acceptable, we would always try to run our full suite as a blocking step to deployment.

If execution time increases to the point it's impractical, we run critical tests on every build, and move certain types of test to nightly/scheduled jobs.

There's no one-size-fits-all-answer, so it's important to think about what value you want from these tests.